# Text input covered by IOS keyboard React

Tags: html, ios, reactjs, input, text

In IOS simple html text input hovered by IOS keyboard when focused

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItPef.jpg)

I have simple input:

```
      <input
        ref={inputRef}
        type="text"
        value={answer}
        onChange={handleAnswerChange}
        className="answer-input"
      />
```

and css for this input:

```
.answer-input {
  margin-top: 1vh;
  width: 80%;
  height: 10%;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 24.899999618530273px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-radius: 30px;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 24.899999618530273px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-radius: 30px;
  border: none;
}
```

Do I need something more for it?

I tried to add some directives to css but it didn't help

```
input, input:before, input:after {
  -webkit-user-select: initial;
  -khtml-user-select: initial;
  -moz-user-select: initial;
  -ms-user-select: initial;
  user-select: initial;
}
```